# Why I am getting a invalid checksum response on doing a post request?

Tags: python, rest, post, request

I have tried using a rest client (ARC)for doing a post request to a private API and I am getting correct response but when I switch to python and did the same request using the python request package , the response is this

```
b'{"code":"Invalid Checksum","message":"Invalid Checksum"}'
```

I am using the same URL , header and body tag. Where can I possibly go wrong .

Here is the code snippet

```
import requests
import json

request_args = {"Id": -1,"startDate": "2018-01-13","endDate": "2018-01-14","ProviderId": 1}
                
headers = {'Authorization':'xxxxxx','Content-Type':'application/json','content-md5':'yyyy'}

base_url = "https://myendpoint"
                
response = requests.post(base_url,data=request_args, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: Are you sure the `content-md5` header is identical for the two requests?  Should the value be an integer instead of a string?

Comment: Just consider that as a placeholder @JohnGordon

Comment: Can you show how that value is calculated?